# Would a C compiler actually have an ascii look up table

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ascii

I know there are a few similar questions around relating to this, but it's still not completely clear.

For example: If in my C source file, I have lots of defined string literals, as the compiler is translating this source file, does it go through each character of strings and use a look-up table to get the ascii number for each character?

I'd guess that if entering characters dynamically into a a running C program from standard input, it is the terminal that is translating actual characters to numbers, but then if we have in the code for example :

```
if (ch == 'c'){//.. do something}
```

the compiler must have its own way of understanding and mapping the characters to numbers?

Thanks in advance for some help with my confusion.

Comment: Yes, it has it's own way of understanding it. How - it's up to the specific compiler. Compiler is just another program.

Comment: Characters _are_ numbers. Learn about encodings.

Comment: So you want to know how a compiler works?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I took it to mean "what does 'c' mean". Perhaps my answer is too narrow.

Comment: Is that 'c' an ASCII 'c', a shift-jis 'c' (trick question), a UTF-8 'c', a UTF-16 'c', or something exotic?  Good news, any good compiler will flag it if it thinks it's strange.  Honestly, it will flag just about anything non-ASCII, so that the above code should continue to work fine.

Comment: When you say "ASCII lookup table" what would the C compiler be "looking up"? Strictly speaking, only humans use ASCII lookup tables. To a computer program a character *is* a number. There is no looking up the character to get a number. The character is what you type in, but the number is what the computer (or compiler in this case) sees. The number is what the program sends to the display, but the character is what you see. The mapping occurs between the keyboard hardware and the program, and the program and the display hardware going out.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html

Comment: _[C preprocessor: character sets](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html)_.  (Specific to gcc, but provides some insight...)

Comment: You should first read the  [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) then look inside the source code of existing free software compilers

Comment: How do you think "characters" are stored in the text file to begin with? They're already numbers. Your keyboard produces numbers, stores numbers in the file, and the display uses those numbers to look up the dot-pattern of a font to display. Not sure what you think a "character" is.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Keyboards send key scan codes, not characters.

Comment: And what are scan codes? Numbers, as I said. The concepts of "character" or "letter" exist only in the human mind.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker , so the compiler will just see a number when it encounters the character , 'c' , for example? So from my understanding it is just the text editor which is displaying the actual character.

Comment: The text editor isn't "displaying" anything. It just gets the number from a file and sends that number to a display handler that turns it into pixels that you can read. That might happen in software or in hardware. But in any case all a computer can do is push numbers around and operate on them. The computer doesn't know that humans are interpreting some of them as text, or colors, or movements, or whatever.

Comment: My confusion is with the text editor itself and how it encodes the human-readable characters we write to it. If using codeblocks IDE for example or eclipse, i'm guessing the encoding will be in ASCII. Then the characters will have the correct numbers which the compiler can understand? What about using a different text editor with some different type of encoding somehow, how will the compiler know how to interpret it?

Answer (score 4):

The C standard talks about the *source character set*, which the set of characters it expects to find in the source files, and the *execution character set*, which is set of characters used natively by the target platform.

For most modern computers that you're likely to encounter, the source and execution character sets will be the same.

A line like `if (ch == 'c')` will be stored in the source file as a sequence of values from the source character set.  For the `'c'` part, the representation is likely `0x27 0x63 0x27`, where the `0x27`s represent the single quote marks and the `0x63` represents the letter `c`.

If the execution character set of the platform is the same as the source character set, then there's no need to translate the `0x63` to some other value.  It can just use it directly.

If, however, the execution character set of the target is different (e.g., maybe you're cross-compiling for an IBM mainframe that still uses EBCDIC), then, yes, it will need a way to look up the `0x63` it finds in the source file to map it to the actual value for a `c` used in the target character set.

---

Outside the scope of what's defined by the standard, there's the distinction between *character set* and *encoding*.  While a character set tells you what characters can be represented (and what their values are), the encoding tells you how those values are stored in a file.

For "plain ASCII" text, the encoding is typically the identity function:  A `c` has the value 0x63, and it's *encoded* in the file simply as a byte with the value of 0x63.

Once you get beyond ASCII, though, there can be more complex encodings.  For example, if your character set is Unicode, the encoding might be UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32, which represent different ways to store a sequence of Unicode values (code points) in a file.

So if your source file uses a non-trivial encoding, the compiler will have to have an algorithm and/or a lookup table to convert the values it reads from the source file into the source character set before it actually does any parsing.

On most modern systems, the source character set is typically Unicode (or a subset of Unicode).  On Unix-derived systems, the source file encoding is typically UTF-8.  On Windows, the source encoding might be based on a code page, UTF-8, or UTF-16, depending on the code editor used to create the source file.

On many modern systems, the execution character set is also Unicode, but, on an older or less powerful computer (e.g., an embedded system), it might be restricted to ASCII or the characters within a particular code page.

---

**Edited to address follow-on question in the comments**

Any tool that reads text files (e.g., an editor or a compiler) has three options:  (1) assume the encoding, (2) take an educated guess, or (3) require the user to specify it.

Most unix utilities assume UTF-8 because UTF-8 is ubiquitous in that world.

Windows tools usually check for a Unicode byte-order mark (BOM), which can indicate UTF-16 or UTF-8.  If there's no BOM, it might apply some heuristics ([IsTextUnicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx)) to guess the encoding, or it might just assume the file is in the user's current code page.

For files that have only characters from ASCII, guessing wrong usually isn't fatal.  UTF-8 was designed to be compatible with plain ASCII files.  (In fact, every ASCII file is a valid UTF-8 file.)  Also many common code pages are supersets of ASCII, so a plain ASCII file will be interpreted correctly.  It would be bad to guess UTF-16 or UTF-32 for plain ASCII, but that's unlikely given how the heuristics work.

Regular compilers don't expend much code dealing with all of this.  The host environment can handle many of the details.  A cross-compiler (one that runs on one platform to make a binary that runs on a different platform) might have to deal with mapping between character sets and encodings.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now my confusion is with the text editor itself. If using codeblocks IDE for example or eclipse, i'm guessing the encoding will be in ASCII. What about using a different text editor with some different type of encoding somehow, how will the compiler know how to interpret it?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. Except you can drop the ASCII bit, in full generality at least.

The mapping used between `int` literals like `'c'` and the numeric equivalent is a function of the *encoding* used by the architecture that the compiler is targeting. ASCII is one such encoding, but there are others, and the C standard places only minimal requirements on the encoding, an important one being that `'0'` through to `'9'` must be consecutive, in one block, positive and able to fit into a `char`. Another requirement is that 'A' to 'Z' and 'a' to 'z' must be positive values that can fit into a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler is not required to have such a thing. Think a minute about a pre-C11 compiler, reading [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) source and translating for an EBCDIC machine. What use would have an ASCII look-up table in such a compiler?

Also think another minute about how such ASCII look-up table(s) would look like in such a compiler!